# Generating a Dataframe with the first and last day of the past three months

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate the following Dataframe with Pandas:

```
print(last_three_months)
  TimePeriod.Start TimePeriod.End
1       2021-03-01     2021-04-01
2       2021-04-01     2021-05-01
3       2021-05-01     2021-05-31
```

I can generate the first and last day of a certain month with the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
first_day_month = datetime(2021, 3, 1)
last_day_month = firstday_month + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
```

Is there a way to generate this dataframe without having to define each date one by one with long-winded code such as

```
month_x = int(pd.to_datetime("today").strftime("%m"))
monthx_1 = int(pd.to_datetime("today").strftime("%m"))-1
...
```

and assigning each resulting value to a df block one by one?

I'm guessing there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.date_range` and generate the DataFrame as follows:

```
start = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=3, day=1)    
df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range(start, periods=3, freq="MS"), 
                   "End": pd.date_range(start, periods=3, freq="M")})
```

`df` is now:

```
    Start       End
0   2021-03-01  2021-03-31
1   2021-04-01  2021-04-30
2   2021-05-01  2021-05-31
```

Comment: Hey. It says invalid syntax for periods=3. Do you not get this error?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited it. Got too caught up in the formatting -_-

Comment: Thanks. This currently makes the period between dates be 2 months instead of 1. I'm tinkering with the variables to make it work.

Comment: Re-edited. Hopefully that's what you need :)

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.